# symbol look up error in electron: undefined symbol gbm_bo_get_modifier

Tags: electron, electron-builder, rhel7

I have a electron app (electron v23) that uses electron_builder to create a AppImage file.

My production client has the following RHEL version that is frozen without any updates (isolated network):
`3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64`

I have given them an application version v1.1 which worked just fine. I did some code updates (added logging with winston) and gave them v1.2 which started showing the below error:

`/tmp/.mount_xyz/myapp: symbol lookup error: /tmp/.mount_xyz/myapp: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_get_modifier`

The electron app is supposed to load and open `http:lanip:port/otherapp` as a starting point in a browser window. This error shows up right at the start in the terminal and immediately terminates (run using the command `./myapp.AppImage --no-sandbox`)

I have reverted to my old github tag v1.1 and rebuilt the app, even this still gives the same error now.

I tried nuking my node_modules each time and tried building in Node v14.21.4, v16.20.0 and v18.15.0 (the previous working executable was created using v16.20.0).

I tried using strace to see if any of the loaded libraries are from a different location than intended. I could not find any significant clues there either. Let me know if you wish to see these results.

The only reference to this bug I found is [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6cdb3b2997c6e823d625553f27fcf11b96346aaa). But I don't see how they are related.

As of now I cannot build a new version that works in the production environment and am looking for any clues about how to debug or fix this issue.

Any more clues or direction to debug are most welcome. Thanks.

I tried installing the same RHEL version in a local version and I don't see these errors in that machine.